# Pixelated cross-browser image scaling

Tags: javascript, css, image, cross-browser, scale

I would like to scale an image up with scale = 2.0. I would like do to that **without** any smoothing, so the desired effect is to turn each pixel of the original image into 2x2 pixels of the same colour.

I wonder if this is possible to do in Javascript/CSS in a cross-browser (>= IE7) manner without resorting to `<canvas />` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I don't believe the effect you want is possible cross-browser without a canvas.

In Firefox in Canvas you can do `ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;` but that's as close as you're going to get.

`image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;` might help you in firefox for CSS scaling, and `-ms-interpolation-mode`* might help you in IE, but I doubt you'll get a solution that looks the same across all browsers.

* I think this has been deprecated/obsoleted.

Comment: That's unfortunate, if nothing else appears, I'll accept your answer and look for a workaround somewhere else. I think I've also read that 'moz-crisp-edges' works only with some recent versions of firefox, though I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

Any details of rendering methods e.g. anti-aliasing/smoothing are out of CSS 2.1 scope. So the answer is 'no' for CSS 2.1.  Image object in JS does not have scaling features either. So 'no' again.

Answer (score 1):

I know flash is a dying technology, however this is some pretty excellent image manipulation scrips should you wish to check that out. This seems a little complex for standard web based image processing although Sounds like a wicked idea!

Comment: Well my whole webapp is written in html+js, so this is not an option. Also I'd agree flash is dying.